# Php mysql update with a new unique id

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I would like to update the id of a mysql row but with the next free id available

Easy to explain but I can't figure it out.

Thank you

Edit:

The point is that I need to have a brand new id for an existing row but I still want to keep everything that is inside the row (lot of data).
This is because a third party system that deals with product payment will only accept an order ID once. 
It seems logical to me to keep the data as it is if the user cancels the transaction and only update the id for a new attempt as the older id is useless and it is tedious to move all the data to a brand new record.
It is something that can obviously be done for a non-auto-incremented id so I believe that it would be possible with an auto-incremented one.
The issue is to be sure that the new id is an available one and, if possible, the next available one.

Comment: What's wrong with the id that is already there?

Comment: if 'it' gets a new id, its not an update (by definition)

Comment: that new id wouldn't get assigned until a new row is `INSERT`ed anyways. An update cannot do an `insert` except in a few limited circumstances, none of which probably apply to you.

Comment: I edited the question for some explanation

Comment: bad idea, keep the original record and create a new one.

Comment: I would like to say that I don't get why my question is considered as off-topic as it is as specific as it gets: I need to update a specific row and I encounter a specific problem. The question is simple because the problem is simple. And it's not a "why" but a "how" question either. It may be a noobie question but not an irrelevant one. The fact that the next available  id is all about insertion and not about updating is a legitimate pro answer to a legitimate noobie question. Unless this website is for advanced users only (is it?), I really don't get the vote. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the id is auto increment you can just insert new record and delete old one.
Doesnt seem logical though. Why would you need to update the id?

Comment: I edited the question for some explanation